# Checking if the variable is of the correct type and its T if of the specified interface

Tags: c#

=== Problem Solved and the best solution added to the code ===

Hello I have the following problem.
As you can see in the code below I have a command stack that holds commands.
There are more than one types of command and each command class can have a different T parameter although this can only be a class that inherits IModel interface.

And now when I want to check if a certain type of command is currently on the stack. I (until I do something wrong) have to specify the whole type with its template which is very inconvenient as it may lead to a very long if-else statement.

I would like to specify the class type but I do not care about its template type. Is there a way to do it?

Below the whole code that you can just copy and run. It's fully executable and precisely shows what I want to achieve.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public interface IModel { }
    class SomeDataModelA : IModel { }
    class SomeDataModelB : IModel { }
    // in reality there is more models and all of them implements IModel

    public interface IUndoRedoCommand 
    {
        void Undo();
        void Redo();
    }

    class RemoveCommand<IModel> : IUndoRedoCommand
    {
        public void Undo() => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public void Redo() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    class AddCommand<IModel> : IUndoRedoCommand
    {
        public void Undo() => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public void Redo() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public class UndoRedoList<T> : List<T>
        where T : IModel
    {
        readonly CommandStack _commandStack;

        public UndoRedoList(CommandStack commandStack)
            : base()
        {
            _commandStack = commandStack;
        }

        public UndoRedoList(int capacity, CommandStack commandStack)
            : base(capacity)
        {
            _commandStack = commandStack;
        }

        public UndoRedoList(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, CommandStack commandStack)
            : base(enumerable)
        {
            _commandStack = commandStack;
        }

        public void AddWithUndoRedoTracking(T item)
        {
            Add(item);
            _commandStack.Push(new AddCommand<T>());
        }

        public void RemoveWithUndoRedoTracking(T item)
        {
            Remove(item);
            _commandStack.Push(new RemoveCommand<T>());
        }

        public void InsertWithUndoRedoTracking(int index, T item)
            => _commandStack.Push(new AddCommand<T>());
    }

    public class CommandStack
    {
        public int UndoCount => _pointer;
        public int RedoCount => _undoRedoStack.Count - _pointer;

        readonly IList<IUndoRedoCommand> _undoRedoStack = new List<IUndoRedoCommand>();
        int _pointer; // points at first redo - so first undo will be _pointer - 1

        public void Push(IUndoRedoCommand cmd) => _undoRedoStack.Insert(_pointer++, cmd);

        public void Refresh()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _undoRedoStack.Count; i++)
            {
                IUndoRedoCommand cmd = _undoRedoStack[i];
                if (cmd is AddCommand<IModel>)
                    Console.WriteLine("This doesn't work but it should.");

                if(cmd is AddCommand<SomeDataModelA>
                   || cmd is AddCommand<SomeDataModelB>
                   /* and so on for all models*/)
                    Console.WriteLine("This works but it is ugly.");

                // perfect solution by Sweeper
                if (cmd.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AddCommand<>))
                    Console.WriteLine("This works too!! Thank you Sweeper.");
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var stack = new CommandStack();
            var list = new UndoRedoList<SomeDataModelA>(stack);

            list.AddWithUndoRedoTracking(new SomeDataModelA());
            list.AddWithUndoRedoTracking(new SomeDataModelA());

            stack.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While Pushing to stack don't create create concrete class implementation. Instead make use of your interface `IModel` for loose coupling - The Snipppet is             `stack.Push(new AddCommand<IModel>());
            stack.Push(new RemoveCommand<IModel>());` - Is this your expected result ?

Comment: Why should you declare something like AddCommand<IModel> if IModel is a generic type argument. (If it does compile, the <IModel> has absolutly nothing to do with your interface IModel, it is a new generic parameter not used for anything).
Get rid of that parameter and you are fine.
Maybe you want `class AddCommand : IUndoRedoCommand { IModel Model {get;set;} }` or you want `AddCommand<T> where T : IModel`

Comment: @user2932057 - that's a good solution but these elements are added in a bit more complicated manner I'll edit the code to show that.

Comment: @Holder - the whole idea was to have this limitation so none other interfaces mat be used accidentally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition?view=netframework-4.8), and compare the types with `==`:

```
if(cmd.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AddCommand<>)) {

}
```

Note that this won't work if you want subclasses of `AddCommand` to also enter the `if`.

Comment: Perfect this is what I needed! Thank you very much.